# Can't reset MySQL password

Tags: mysql, ssh, server, whm

I had some tweaking for my server and unfortunately I can't log to phpmyadmin via whm anymore nore via ssh as I have access denied for root@localhost.
I tried to change my sql root password via whm but it give me the following error :

> Unable to reset the MySQL root password.
>   The subprocess reported error number 1 when it ended.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check if you are able to login to mysql from a command prompt. Login to your server via SSH and issue a mysql. It should login to your mysql server.

If that doesn't work then do a cat /root/.my.cnf. There you should have the previous mysql root password. Copy that password and try this:

mysql -u root -p (then when prompted paste the password if you have copied earlier).

If you get an authentication failed message then that password is not the correct one and you have to manually change (you said you can't change it from WHM).

Do you use a local mysql server or a remote mysql server?

In order to change the mysql root password you have to stop the mysql service on the server and start it manually with skip grants option.

Depending on your CentOS version you have to options to stop the mysql service:

```
- CentOS 6.x - /etc/init.d/mysql stop
- CentOS 7.x - systemctl stop mysql
```

Then manually start the mysql service:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Then issue the following:

```
mysql --user=root mysql
update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Restart mysql and you should be able to login with your new password. You might also want to save it in /root/.my.cnf as well.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Bogdan, seems you have to issue one more command: use mysql; 
And it's quite possible that issuing the command: `update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';`
you will be errored that there is no field Password. It happens if you're running mysql server version 5.7+. In such case change command as follows:

```
use mysql;update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
```